# Working with data from CSV with Python without using Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, csv, dictionary, average

I am very new to using python to process data on CSV files. I have a CSV file with the data below. I want to take the **averages of the time stamps** for each Sprint, Jog, and Walk column **by session**. The below example has the subject **John Doe** and **Session2** and **Session3** that I would like to find the averages of separately and write them to a new CSV file. Is there a way not using PANDAS but other modules like CSV or Numpy to gather the data by the person (subject) and then by **session**. I have tried to make a dictionary but the keys get overwritten. I have also tried using a List but I cannot figure out how to target the sessions to average them out. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I also tried using dictReader to read the fieldnames and then to process the data but I cannot figure out how to group all the John Doe Session2 data to find the average of the times.

```
Subject, Session, Course, Size, Category, Sprint, Jog, Walk
John Doe, Session2, 17, 2, Bad, 25s, 36s, 55s
John Doe, Session2, 3, 2, Good, 26s, 35s, 45s
John Doe, Session2, 1, 2, Good, 22s, 31s, 47s
John Doe, Session3, 5, 2, Good, 16s, 32s, 55s
John Doe, Session3, 2, 2, Good, 13s, 24s, 52s
John Doe, Session3, 16, 2, Bad, 15s, 26s, 49s
```

PS I say no PANDAS because my groupmates are not adding this module since we have so many other dependencies.

Comment: Have a try with Python's [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and post your code.

Comment: @tdelaney how did you put it in a code block? :(

Comment: Have a read of Stackoverflow's [editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: I just selected the text and hit the `{}` button. All that did was indent everything 4 spaces. You could do that manually if you'd like. Click into "edited" and press the markdown button and you'll see the exact text changes. And you can change it back if you don't like it! We tend to tidy up without permission and sometimes get it wrong!

Comment: @tdelaney thanks, I didn't know how to do that. Haha I tried to make it as close to that style as I could. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your input, these built-in Python libraries can generate the output you want:

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict

with open('input.csv','r',newline='') as fin,open('output.csv','w',newline='') as fout:

    # skip needed because sample data had spaces after comma delimiters.
    reader = csv.DictReader(fin,skipinitialspace=True)

    # Output file will have these fieldnames
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fout,fieldnames='Subject Session Sprint Jog Walk'.split())
    writer.writeheader()

    # for each subject/session, groupby returns a 2-tuple of sort key and an
    # iterator over the rows of that key.  Data must be sorted by the key already!
    for (subject,session),group in groupby(reader,key=itemgetter('Subject','Session')):

        # built the row to output.  defaultdict(int) assumes integer(0) if key doesn't exist.
        row = defaultdict(int)
        row['Subject'] = subject
        row['Session'] = session

        # Count the items for average.
        count = 0
        for item in group:
            count += 1

            # sum the rows, removing the 's'
            for col in ('Sprint','Jog','Walk'):
                row[col] += int(item[col][:-1])

        # produce the average
        for col in ('Sprint','Jog','Walk'):
            row[col] /= count

        writer.writerow(row)
```

Output:

```
Subject,Session,Sprint,Jog,Walk
John Doe,Session2,24.333333333333332,34.0,49.0
John Doe,Session3,14.666666666666666,27.333333333333332,52.0
```

Function links: [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)
[groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
[defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

If your data is not pre-sorted, you can use the following replacement lines to read in and sort the data by using the same key used in `groupby`.  However, in this implementation the data must be small enough to load it all into memory at once.

```
    sortkey = itemgetter('Subject','Session')
    data = sorted(reader,key=sortkey)
    for (subject,session),group in groupby(data,key=sortkey):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want the average grouped by subject and session, just compose unique keys out of that information:

```
import csv
times = {}
with open('yourfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile[1:]:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','):
        key = row[0]+row[1]
        if key not in times.keys():
            times[key] = row[-3:]
        else:
            times[key].extend(row[-3:])
average = {k: sum([int(entry[:-1]) for entry in v])/len(v) for k, v in times.items()}
```

This assumes that the first two entries do have regular structure as in your example and there is no ambiguity when composing the two first entries per row. To be sure one could insert a special delimiter between them in the key.
If you are also the person storing the data: Writing the unit of a column in the column header saves transformation effort later and avoids redundant information storage.